# Parse Backend with Windows 8.1 Phone Development

Tags: parse-platform, sdk, windows-phone-8.1, nuget-package

I am trying to use Parse Backend Services in my app and I was installing their Nuget Package in my project.

But it's showing the following error.

`Install-Package : Could not install package 'parse 1.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

Is there anyway to use Parse Backend Service in Windows 8.1 Phone Development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It seems now that Parse is now also supporting .NET with full support to .net framework 4.5.